# Is there a scoping problem with assigning my class window handle to a global in InitInstance() versus in WinProc()?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

In the code below as indicated the global assignment of the handle returned from the call to `CreateWindowW()` seemed to go out of scope.  I could not access it outside of `InitInstance()`.  When I moved the assignment into `WinProc()`, it remained in scope in other functions that I accessed it in.

```
HWND hWndTop;                                   // Handle to top window
       .
       .

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
       .
       .

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass,....

   hWndTop = hWnd;   // This did not work.
       .
       .
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

   hWndTop = hWnd;    // This did work.

      .
      .
}
```

Comment: I bet both of them work. It's just that your WndProc is trying to use `hWndTop` before `InitInstance` can set its value. In other words, the issue is not "my assignment to hWndTop is being undone". The issue is "my assignment to hWndTop hasn't happened yet."

Comment: Okay.  I wondered if that might be the case.

Comment: `CreateWindow()` will send a few messages to `WndProc()`, such as `WM_(NC)CREATE`, `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, etc, before exiting to `InitInstance()`. So, `hWndTop` won't have been set yet for every message that `WndProc()` receives

Comment: Okay.  I guess there is no problem with it begin "re-declared" every time it enters `WndProc()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...It's just that your `WndProc` is trying to use `hWndTop` before `InitInstance` can set its value. In other words, the issue is not "my assignment to `hWndTop` is being undone". The issue is "my assignment to `hWndTop` hasn't happened yet." – Raymond Chen

> `CreateWindow()` will send a few messages to `WndProc()`, such as `WM_(NC)CREATE`, `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, etc, before exiting to `InitInstance()`. So, `hWndTop` won't have been set yet for every message that `WndProc()` receives – Remy Lebeau